# PHP DOMDocument replace DOMElement child with HTML string

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

Using PHP I'm attempting to take an HTML string passed from a WYSIWYG editor and replace the children of an element inside of a preloaded HTML document with the new HTML.

So far I'm loading the document identifying the element I want to change by ID but the process to convert an HTML to something that can be placed inside a DOMElement is eluding me.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$element = $doc->getElementById($item_id);
if(isset($element)){
    //Remove the old children from the element
    while($element->childNodes->length){
        $element->removeChild($element->firstChild);
    }

    //Need to build the new children from $html_string and append to $element
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the HTML string can be parsed as XML, you can do this (after clearing the element of all child nodes):

```
$fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML($html_string);
$element->appendChild($fragment);
```

If $html_string cannot be parsed as XML, it will fail. If it does, you’ll have to use loadHTML(), which is less strict — but it will add elements around the fragment which you will have to strip.

Unlike PHP, Javascript has the innerHTML property which allows you to do this very easily. I needed something like it for a project so I extended PHP’s DOMElement to include Javascript-like innerHTML access.

With it you can access the innerHTML property and change it just as you would in Javascript:

```
echo $element->innerHTML;
$elem->innerHTML = '<a href="http://example.org">example</a>';
```

---

Source: http://www.keyvan.net/2012/11/php-domdocument-replace-domelement-child-with-html-string/

Comment: @Greg, shouldn't I decide where my contributions go? And since when did you speak for the world? I decided to move my contributions over to my own blog after some of my contributions were deleted from StackOverflow and hidden from me. I'd like to keep it that way, so please revert the change.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Source: [*How to answer*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Greg, I'm aware of the guidelines. I posted the answer here originally and moved it to my own site due to the way my other contributions were handled on this site - as I mentioned above, they were deleted and hidden from me. Why you object so much to a link is beyond me. Some food for thought from one of the creators of this site http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/08/are-you-a-digital-sharecropper.html "Can your contributions be revoked, deleted, or permanently taken offline without your consent?" On Stackoverflow: yes. On my own site: no.

Comment: The link wasn't deleted by me, I merely expanded the content so we had the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Keyvan: But you published on Stackoverflow in the first place. If you remove it later on but other users decide to keep the content, there is nothing wrong with keeping the content.

Answer (score 3):

The current accepted answer suggests using appendXML(), but acknowledges that it won't handle complex html such as what is returned from a WYSISYG editor as specified in the original question. As suggested loadHTML() can address this. but no one has yet shown how.

This is what I believe is the best/correct answer to the original question addressing encoding issues, "Document Fragment is empty" warnings and "Wrong Document Error" errors that someone is likely to hit if they write this from scratch. I know I found them after following the hints in the previous responses.

This is code from a site I support that inserts WordPress sidebar content into the $content of a post.  It assumes that $doc is a valid DOMDocument similar to the way $doc is defined in the original question. It also assumes that $element is the tag after which you wish to insert the sidebarcontent (or whatever).

```
            // NOTE: Cannot use a document fragment here as the AMP html is too complex for the appendXML function to accept.
            // Instead create it as a document element and insert that way.
            $node = new DOMDocument();
            // Note that we must encode it correctly or strange characters may appear.
            $node->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $sidebarContent, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8') );
            // Now we need to move this document element into the scope of the content document 
            // created above or the insert/append will be rejected.
            $node = $doc->importNode( $node->documentElement, true );
            // If there is a next sibling, insert before it.
            // If not, just add it at the end of the element we did find.
            if (  $element->nextSibling ) {
                $element->parentNode->insertBefore( $node, $element->nextSibling );
            } else {
                $element->parentNode->appendChild($node);
            }
```

After all of this is done, if you don't want to have the source of a full HTML document with body tags and what not, you can generate the more localized html with this:

```
    // Now because we have moved the post content into a full document, we need to get rid of the 
    // extra elements that make it a document and not a fragment
    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'body' );
    $body = $body->item(0);

    // If you need an element with a body tag, you can do this.
    // return $doc->savehtml( $body );

    // Extract the html from the body tag piece by piece to ensure valid html syntax in destination document
    $bodyContent = ''; 
    foreach( $body->childNodes as $node ) { 
            $bodyContent .= $body->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $node ); 
    } 
    // Now return the full content with the new content added. 
    return $bodyContent;
```

Comment: @Damneddani Note that the savehtml( $body ) ends up returning HTML WITH a body tag.  If you are inserting the html into another page, that will produce invalid html.  Try doing something like this:

           $rootContent = '';

           foreach( $rootNode->childNodes as $node ){
               $rootContent .= $rootNode->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $node );
           }

           // No return the full content with sidebar content added.
           return $rootContent;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loadHTML()` on a fragment of code and then append the resulting created nodes into the original DOM tree.

Comment: Would you be suggesting creating a new DOMDocument using load HTML then taking the children of the new Document's body tag and appending them to the orginal DOM?  Or is there another loadHTML() function I'm missing.

Comment: I really hate how html and body tags are added automatically when you do things like saveHTML() or loadHTML(). Is there an easy workaround other than writing a wrapper that would strip them off?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread (but reply on this because also looking for a solution to this). I have made an easy method to replace content with just one single line when using it. To understand the method better, I also add some context named functions.

This is now a part of my library, so that's the reason of all function names here, all functions starts with the prefix 'su'.

It is very easy to use and very powerful (and quite less code).

**Here is the code:**

```
function suSetHtmlElementById( &$oDoc, &$s, $sId, $sHtml, $bAppend = false, $bInsert = false, $bAddToOuter = false )
 {
    if( suIsValidString( $s ) && suIsValidString( $sId ))
    {
     $bCreate = true;
     if( is_object( $oDoc ))
     {
       if( !( $oDoc instanceof DOMDocument ))
        { return false; }
       $bCreate = false;
     }

     if( $bCreate )
      { $oDoc = new DOMDocument(); }

     libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
     $oDoc->loadHTML($s);
     libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
     $oNode = $oDoc->getElementById( $sId );

     if( is_object( $oNode ))
     { 
       $bReplaceOuter = ( !$bAppend && !$bInsert );

       $sId = uniqid('SHEBI-');
       $aId = array( "<!-- $sId -->", "<!--$sId-->" );

       if( $bReplaceOuter )
       {
         if( suIsValidString( $sHtml ) )
         {
             $oNode->parentNode->replaceChild( $oDoc->createComment( $sId ), $oNode );
             $s = $oDoc->saveHtml();
             $s = str_replace( $aId, $sHtml, $oDoc->saveHtml());
         }
         else { $oNode->parentNode->removeChild( $oNode ); 
                $s = $oDoc->saveHtml();
              }
         return true;
       }

       $bReplaceInner = ( $bAppend && $bInsert );
       $sThis = null;

       if( !$bReplaceInner )
       {
         $sThis = $oDoc->saveHTML( $oNode );
         $sThis = ($bInsert?$sHtml:'').($bAddToOuter?$sThis:(substr($sThis,strpos($sThis,'>')+1,-(strlen($oNode->nodeName)+3)))).($bAppend?$sHtml:''); 
       }

       if( !$bReplaceInner && $bAddToOuter )
       { 
          $oNode->parentNode->replaceChild( $oDoc->createComment( $sId ), $oNode );
          $sId = &$aId;
       }
       else { $oNode->nodeValue = $sId; }

       $s = str_replace( $sId, $bReplaceInner?$sHtml:$sThis, $oDoc->saveHtml());
       return true;
     }
    } 
    return false; 
 }

// A function of my library used in the function above:
function suIsValidString( &$s, &$iLen = null, $minLen = null, $maxLen = null )
{
  if( !is_string( $s ) || !isset( $s{0} ))
   { return false; }

  if( $iLen !== null )
   { $iLen = strlen( $s ); }

  return (( $minLen===null?true:($minLen > 0 && isset( $s{$minLen-1} ))) && 
           $maxLen===null?true:($maxLen >= $minLen && !isset( $s{$maxLen})));   
}
```

**Some context functions:**

```
 function suAppendHtmlById( &$s, $sId, $sHtml, &$oDoc = null )
 { return suSetHtmlElementById( $oDoc, $s, $sId, $sHtml, true, false ); }

 function suInsertHtmlById( &$s, $sId, $sHtml, &$oDoc = null )
 { return suSetHtmlElementById( $oDoc, $s, $sId, $sHtml, false, true ); }

 function suAddHtmlBeforeById( &$s, $sId, $sHtml, &$oDoc = null )
 { return suSetHtmlElementById( $oDoc, $s, $sId, $sHtml, false, true, true ); }

 function suAddHtmlAfterById( &$s, $sId, $sHtml, &$oDoc = null )
 { return suSetHtmlElementById( $oDoc, $s, $sId, $sHtml, true, false, true ); }

 function suSetHtmlById( &$s, $sId, $sHtml, &$oDoc = null )
 { return suSetHtmlElementById( $oDoc, $s, $sId, $sHtml, true, true ); }

 function suReplaceHtmlElementById( &$s, $sId, $sHtml, &$oDoc = null )
 { return suSetHtmlElementById( $oDoc, $s, $sId, $sHtml, false, false ); }

 function suRemoveHtmlElementById( &$s, $sId, &$oDoc = null )
 { return suSetHtmlElementById( $oDoc, $s, $sId, null, false, false ); }
```

**How to use it:**

In the following examples, I assume that there is already content loaded into a variable called `$sMyHtml` and the variable `$sMyNewContent` contains some new html. The variable `$sMyHtml` contains an element called/with the id '`example_id`'.

```
// Example 1: Append new content to the innerHTML of an element (bottom of element):
if( suAppendHtmlById( $sMyHtml, 'example_id', $sMyNewContent ))
 { echo $sMyHtml; }
 else { echo 'Element not found?'; }

// Example 2: Insert new content to the innerHTML of an element (top of element):
suInsertHtmlById( $sMyHtml, 'example_id', $sMyNewContent );    

// Example 3: Add new content ABOVE element:
suAddHtmlBeforeById( $sMyHtml, 'example_id', $sMyNewContent );    

// Example 3: Add new content BELOW/NEXT TO element:
suAddHtmlAfterById( $sMyHtml, 'example_id', $sMyNewContent );    

// Example 4: SET new innerHTML content of element:
suSetHtmlById( $sMyHtml, 'example_id', $sMyNewContent );    

// Example 5: Replace entire element with new content:
suReplaceHtmlElementById( $sMyHtml, 'example_id', $sMyNewContent );    

// Example 6: Remove entire element:
suSetHtmlElementById( $sMyHtml, 'example_id' );
```

Comment: Brilliant work! Super useful.  What is `$oDoc` used for -- is that to pass an existing domdoc object? You should make this into a library and document it I think.

Comment: @Miro After all this time, thanks mate! $oDoc is an parameter that you can use to pass an instance of a DOMDocument to avoid the function needs to create a DOMDocument instance each time you call it. So if you want to do many operations on the same, you better first create an instance of DOMDocument yourself to reduce overhead and time.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but none of the current answers show a minimal working example of how to replace DOMNode(s) in a DOMDocument with an HTML stored in a string.

```php
// the HTML fragment we want to use as the replacement
$htmlReplace = '<div><strong>foo</strong></div>';
// the HTML of the original document
$htmlHaystack = '<p><a id="tag">bar</a></p>';

// load the HTML replacement fragment
$domDocumentReplace = new \DOMDocument;
$domDocumentReplace->loadHTML($htmlReplace, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

// load the HTML of the document
$domDocumentHaystack = new \DOMDocument;
$domDocumentHaystack->loadHTML($htmlHaystack, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

// import the replacement node into the document
$htmlReplaceNode = $domDocumentHaystack->importNode($domDocumentReplace->documentElement, true);

// find the DOMNode(s) we want to replace - in this case #tag (to keep the example simple)
$domNodeTag = $domDocumentHaystack->getElementById('tag');

// replace the node
$domNodeTag->parentNode->replaceChild($htmlReplaceNode, $domNodeTag);

// output the new HTML of the document
echo $domDocumentHaystack->saveHTML($domDocumentHaystack->documentElement);
// <p><div><strong>foo</strong></div></p>
```