# DOMDocument append already fixed html from string

Tags: php, domdocument

So im trying to show a snapshot html from a page using DOMDocument. What i have so far is my home page which i load from a remote location

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($remote);
```

then i choose two elements, my head area and a div inside main content where i will be adding my content (html took from a string variable)

```
$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$noticia2 = $dom->getElementById('content_home');
```

following this i have added content to my script tag

```
$jquery = '$(document).ready(function(){ $("#feed_home").hide()});
      if (window.location.hash) {
        Destino = window.location.hash.replace(\'#!\', \'?\');

             window.location.href = window.location.href.split(\'#\')[0] + Destino;
    }


';    

$script = $dom->createElement('script', $jquery);
$script_type = $dom->createAttribute('type');

$script_type->value = 'application/javascript';
$script->appendChild($script_type);

$head->appendChild($script);
```

Then i go through my database and i collect some info which i will be formating with html tags in a big $content string using mysql_fetch_array. And now my problem.... whenever i try to append this inside my $div node i cant manage to have this content treated as HTML so im having problems displaying this stuff.

```
$div = $dom->createElement('div', $content);
$div_class = $dom->createAttribute('class');
$div_class->value = 'noticia-ajax';
$div->appendChild($div_class);
$noticia2->appendChild($div);
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

What i get is a normal page, with my div "noticia-ajax" well formed and then inside this guy i have

```
SOME TEXT <BR> AND NO HTML TAG TREATED AS HTML TAG <BR> SOMETHING LIKE THIS
```

And ofcourse i would like to have all of this tags read as html! right?

Comment: sorry! no... its a string with html ! NO ARRAY, my bad.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233683/php-domdocument-replace-domelement-child-with-html-string/17661043#17661043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to do is create a document fragment:

```
$div = $dom->createElement( 'div'); // No $contents here
$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML( $content);
$div->appendChild( $fragment);
```

Comment: why append XML instad of child?

Comment: @FoNko - appendChild expects a DOMNode, you don't have one. All you have is a string of XML (in this case, HTML) data.

Comment: it says document fragment is empty :S for line $div->appendChild( $fragment);

Comment: That `<br>` tag needs to be `<br />`, when it is, [it works for me](http://3v4l.org/YPQFY).

Comment: lol... im pushing it to hard to my brain...i need to rest! THANKS SR!

Comment: just as a note, I was trying something similar and had to add this to avoid malformed xml from taking down the site (the string I want to inject is provided by site administrators, who may not know the difference between xml and html):  `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  if( simplexml_load_string( $output ) ) { ... }`  The result is if it is malformed xml, it will not be added.