# PHP DomDocument appendChildNode where I have <i> tags in the text

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument, xmlnode

I would like to append some text to a dom element as a child node.

The problem is that in the text I can have tags as `<i>`, `<bold>` etc.

Actually, with this method:

```
private function appendChildNode($dom_output, $cit_node, $nodeName, $nodeText)
{
    if ($nodeText != null && $nodeText != "" ) {
        $node = $dom_output->createElement($nodeName);
        $node->appendChild($dom_output->createTextNode($nodeText));
        $cit_node->appendChild($node);
        return $node;
    }
}
```

When I have tags in the $nodeText, then the `<i>` will be converted to `&lt;i&gt;` and so on.

How can I append this text by keeping the tags as they are?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution.

Thanks to this post: [DOMDocument append already fixed html from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670374/domdocument-append-already-fixed-html-from-string)

I did:

```
private function appendChildNode($dom_output, $cit_node, $nodeName, $nodeText)
{
    if ($nodeText != null && $nodeText != "" ) {        
        $node = $dom_output->createElement($nodeName);
        $fragment = $dom_output->createDocumentFragment();
        $fragment->appendXML( $nodeText);
        $node->appendChild($fragment);
        $cit_node->appendChild($node);
        return $node;
    }
}
```